# Who is user 'dredington'@'localhost'?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just started using mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

When I try an insert, I get the error:

```
Access denied for user 'dredington'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'm sure I can figure out what I'm doing wrong, but this appears to be a common problem:

[Google search for that string](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=fqDoU-jbOIiJ8QfFo4C4Dg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%20Access%20denied%20for%20user%20'dredington'%40'localhost'%20(using%20password%3A%20NO))

So who is 'dredington'? Where did this come from?

**To clarify: this is not a technical help question** - I was writing the query wrong and have fixed it. But 'dredington' is nowhere in my code. Just wondering where it originates in the history of MySQL?

Comment: What is the value of your `$dbuser` variable?

Comment: Your google search doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: it simply means somewhere on the code ..it is set like `$dbuser = 'dredington'`

Comment: dredington is the user. You must have given this user some password. Use that in mysqli funciton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) says that the default user, if you haven't set `$dbuser`, will be the value of `ini_get("mysqli.default_user")`, so 'dredington' was presumably set by your web hosting company in their php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

This will try  to open with the username and password that you supply.
The value of dbuser will be used as the username and dbpass as password.
You need to set these two values.